# OHAttributedLabel numberOfLines

Tags: iphone, ios

This is in reference to [**OHAttributedLabel numberOfLines**](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/issues/34) issue. I have created an **OHAttributedLabel** and on setting attributedText I get a crash in my application. The text to be displayed on label may be be of multiple lines as it is coming from server.
What is the solution for this?

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:string];
[attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.f green:0.f blue:0.5 alpha:1.f] range:[string rangeOfString:matchingStringPhone]];
            label.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Getting crash in second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler should warn you there is no setTextColor:range: method in class NSMutableAttributedString.
My is doing so at least.
Your?

May be you want to call
- (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes range:(NSRange)aRange
???

Comment: I commented it and after third line added the following line :         [label addCustomLink:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] inRange:[string rangeOfString:matchingStringPhone]];  Still getting crash.

Comment: do you suppose addCustomLink:inRange: exists in UILable??? Turn compiler warnings on! It will save you!

Comment: label is not UILabel. It is OHAttributedLabel which has addCustomLink:inRange: defined for it.

Comment: And how can -(void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes range:(NSRange)aRange help me?

Comment: Nothing is coming on log on crash. I saw [this](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) for OHAttributedLabel.

Comment: It was some mistale on my end. Got out of the crash. But not able to see any text.